# How to hide the Property name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, abp

It's a lot that I used MVC but I need to create a widget using Abp.IO,
What I currently got is

[image]

But I want to hide this SenzaAgente and ConAgente, I think this is generated since I use abp-input and it get the value of the property, does exist a way of hiding it and gaining the space (The SENZA Agente on the left should be on the same line of the number)

The code I used is

```
<abp-table hoverable-rows="true" responsive-sm="true">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>% RINCARO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SENZA Agente</td>
            <td><abp-input readonly="true" asp-for="@Model.Rincaro.SenzaAgente"></abp-input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CON Agente</td>
            <td><abp-input readonly="true" asp-for="@Model.Rincaro.ConAgente"></abp-input></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</abp-table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use suppress-label="true" attribute

```cs
<abp-table hoverable-rows="true" responsive-sm="true">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>% RINCARO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SENZA Agente</td>
            <td><abp-input suppress-label="true" readonly="true" asp-for="@Model.Rincaro.SenzaAgente"></abp-input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CON Agente</td>
            <td><abp-input suppress-label="true" readonly="true" asp-for="@Model.Rincaro.ConAgente"></abp-input></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</abp-table>
```